# What Can Dissolve Polypyrrole?

Tags: polymers, solvents

I am looking for a solvent for polypyrrole. I read M-cresol and chloroform can be used, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Unmodified or (partly) protonated and with counterions, such as arylalkyl sulfonates or polystyrene sulfonate?

Comment: Without reacting with polypyrrole it is not possible to dissolve it. Whoever is demanding in paper that they have succeeded in dissolving the pure polypyrrole, without transforming to its derivative, its wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polypyrrole is quite a rigid polymer (one of the reasons it's a conductive polymer) and it's generally not considered particularly soluble without being derivatized. It seems to be [possible](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0379677999002672) to dissolve it somewhat in polar organic solvents if it's been polymerized with a large anion like dodecylbenzenesulfonate, basically reducing the interactions of the chains of polymer, but it loses some of its conductivity when cast into a film. [One group](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/app.20882/full) has apparently managed to make it water soluble by polymerizing oxidatively with horseradish peroxidase in the presence of a sulfonated polystyrene counterion, which keeps the chain growing linearly along the length of the polystyrene, apparently allowing it to be soluble.